# JTable print with prefix text on top (not header / footer)

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, graphics2d

I would like to print a specific text on the top of a JTable , but not in every page (not header) just on the first page and/or a text on the end of the text but again not as a footer to each page but only after the end of the JTable contents.

How is this possible ?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you just want to put a label above and below the frame containing your table? You really need to clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes , a predefined text above or/and below not onthe table but on the printing of the table whenever the user desire to print it.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add a JLabel above and below your table.

Comment: Jlabel would be great, but I wonder if it will be printed when I print the jtable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTable has a version of print() you could probably use an example.  Take a look at the source code for it.

`public boolean print(PrintMode printMode,
                         MessageFormat headerFormat,
                         MessageFormat footerFormat,
                         boolean showPrintDialog,
                         PrintRequestAttributeSet attr,
                         boolean interactive,
                         PrintService service)`

also look at `getPrintable(...)` method in JTable, and the `javax.swing.TablePrintable` class.  You will have to do some custom printing code, but TablePrintable is a good start.  There is a print() method that takes a pageIndex, and you could do something very much like that, but don't print the header and footer on every page.

Comment: I use the print method of jtable to print my results and works great. Now they only I need is to add some text before and after these resauls but not in every page like footer or header.Only in start and end. Is there a sample code in any tutorial? Thank you!

Comment: I didn't see anything great when I googled it.  Really the code for JTable.print() and [TablePrintable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/TablePrintable.java#TablePrintable.print%28java.awt.Graphics%2Cjava.awt.print.PageFormat%2Cint%29) was the best example.  It will help you to understand how to do what you want.